# DevExpress: Is GridView.RowUpdated supposed to fire for row deletions?

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

For example I have a `KeyDown` handler that calls `view.DeleteRow(view.FocusedRowHandle)` but the `RowUpdated` event on the `gridView` does not seem to fire.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid doesn't provide an event for row deletion (you can find the discussion of these abilities in the thread [DQ52355](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/DQ52355.aspx)). I suggest that you handle required events at the level of your datasource. For example, if you are using a standard DataTable class, you can handle the [DataTable.RowDeleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowdeleted.aspx) event.

P.S. In the future, I suggest you use the [Devexpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) to get official and guaranteed assistance on the use of DevExpress products. Note that FULL SUPPORT IS FREE even during the evaluation period (30 days).

Comment: Thanks.  I am using DataTable, so this worked perfectly.  Still seems odd that this is not part of the GridView.

Regarding DevExpress support center: yes I have support center, but I get such good support here!!  Thanks again.